# Oriented 1-manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have found the following statement in one of my exercises:

Let $W$ be a oriented 1-manifold with boundary. Then its  boundary has "as many positive points as negative points. 
I don't understand this statement, what are "positive" or "negative" points here.

Answer (score 2):

As you consider a 1-manifold, it is a disjoint union of circles and intervals, and the only connected components with boundary are closed intervals. Each of them has an orientation, you can think this as a direction, or an arrow telling you where is left and where is right. A positive point of the boundary is a point on the very right side, and a negative point of the boundary is a point that is on the very left of the interval.

Edit: However, I think you want the manifold to be compact, as else $\mathbb{R}^+$ would be an obvious counterexample.